# Exploding a table into rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

What is the best solution (performance) for exploding a table or matrix from python into rows that contains information from the columns and its values ?

Let us say we have load a table in Pandas as the following:

```
Date    A   B   
t1  1   2   
t2  3   4
```

I want to explode the table so it becomes a series of 4 lines as follows:

```
t1-A-1
t1-B-2
t2-A-3
t2-C-4
```

Performance is key here once there might dozens of columns and hundreds of rows in the original table.

what about the following:

```
Date    A   B   C
t1  1   5   9
t1  2   6   10
t2  3   7   11
t2  4   8   12
```

The output series would be:

```
Date    code
t1  "str1"1"str2"B"str2"5
t1  "str1"2"str2"B"str2"6
t2  "str1"3"str2"B"str2"7
t2  "str1"4"str2"B"str2"8
..  ..
t2  "str1"4"str2"C"str2"12
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What happens to B5 and C3?

Answer (score 3):

If performance is the key... use `numpy`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add as cadd
from functools import reduce

def proc(d1):
    v = d1.values
    n, m = v.shape
    dates = np.repeat(d1.index.values.astype(str), m)
    cols = np.tile(d1.columns.values.astype(str), n)
    vals = v.ravel().astype(str)
    return pd.Series(reduce(cadd, [dates, '-', cols, '-', vals]))

proc(df.set_index('Date'))

0    t1-A-1
1    t1-B-2
2    t2-A-3
3    t2-B-4
dtype: object
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit proc(df.set_index('Date'))
%timeit df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index().apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

*small data*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 494 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
from string import ascii_letters

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 52)),
    pd.Index(['t{:05d}'.format(i) for i in range(1000)], name='Date'),
    list(ascii_letters)
).reset_index()

10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 3.75 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index().apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    t1-A-1
1    t1-B-2
2    t2-A-3
3    t2-B-4
dtype: object
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks.